# I want to add color in TextView.. With any color of your choice

Tags: android, colors, textview

I want to get the `TextView` in color.. Please tell me a code..with any color of your choice..

```
    <TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_margin Left="5 pt" 
    android:layout_margin Right="5 pt" 
    android:text Size="12 pt" 
    android:layout_margin Top="3 pt" 
    android:id="@+id/  Result" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"> 
    </TextView>
```

Comment: add **android:textColor="#445566"** and **TextView** is one word, not "Text View"!!

Comment: thank you!...but i still get the text message in black color :(

Comment: yea bro!.. "Text View" in one word i could not post it here..it was underlined red so i used space :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the `textColor` XML attribute, e.g.:

```
android:textColor="#ffffff"
```

Your whole `TextView` would look like this:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="5pt" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5pt" 
    android:textSize="12pt" 
    android:layout_marginTop="3pt" 
    android:id="@+id/Result" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro! it worked :) dude can u give your email id coz m still a noob in android..i could share my doubts with you :)

Comment: Glad it worked! I won't give you my email address. My best advice is to read a book on Android programming, and do as many test projects as possible. We all had to go through this. Feel free to ask on SO if any questions arise on the way.

Comment: @FD_, wouldn't it be better to use dp/sp units for sizes ?

Comment: @2Dee: Yes, dp is definitely the unit of choice.

Comment: @FD_, PS : I saw the link before you deleted it. You, Sir, just made my day, +1 :-D

Comment: @2Dee Haha great! I've always wanted to post a lmgtfy link on SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use some inbuilt colors like :

```
android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
```